# how to change background color execept one in popup modal

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I search a lot but haven't found any solution, so I posted over here
when I click bootstrap modal, a popup comes up and I apply background color and CSS now my problem is that is it possible to prevent bootstrap modal to apply background color in a particular div.

```
   <div id="modal">
   </div>
   <div id="new-row">
   </div>
```

now i want to prevent background color apply by modal over new-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your concern correctly, then you simply need to define a **background-color** for the new-row and make sure that your CSS file is linked after the bootstrap one.

```css
#modal{
position:absolute;
padding: 100px;
background-color:red;
}

#new-row{
margin-left:50px;
margin-top:50px;
position:absolute;
padding: 50px;
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal"></div>
<div id="new-row"></div>
```